# HTML Dropdown's redirection(using JS) not working on mobile, but works fine on PC

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I have a dropdown on my page:

```
<div class="dropdown" data-method="redirect">
    <select id="weekselect">
        <option>Select a week</option>

        <option value="http://sample.com/page1/action">This Week</option>

    </select>
</div>
```

When an  is selected, it will be redirected to the page http://sample.com/page1/action. It works fine on PC, but when the site is viewed on mobile, the redirection doesn't work, and it simply redirects to a page `undefined`.

The JS code for doing redirection is:

```
$(window).load(function (event) {

    $(document).on('click','#menu-bars', function (event) {
        $('body').toggleClass('nav-collapsed');
        $.scrollTo(0, 'fast');
    });

    var selectList = $('select');

    if( !$('html').is('.touch') ){
        selectList.select2({
            minimumResultsForSearch: -1
        });
    }

    selectList.on("change", function (e) {
        var parent = $(this).parents('.dropdown');
        var method = parent.data('method');


        if (method == 'redirect') {
            window.location = e.val;
        }
```

It's probably that when the site is viewed on mobile, `window.location = e.val;` contains no value.

What could be the possible cause that the js is not working when redirecting the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `e.val`, try using `$(this).val();`

also redirect using `window.location.href`

Comment: I tries this:       
window.location.href = $(this).val();  and now it can redirect on mobile(I tested it in chrome just now.) What is the reason to change the code this way?

Comment: to redirect to a new page, you need to update the value of window.location.href. In your code you are overwriting window.location which is an object containing all of the location meta, hash, methods etc

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
if (method == 'redirect') {
            window.location = e.val;
        }
```

to

```
if (method == 'redirect') {
            window.location = $(this).val();
        }
```

`e` isn't the calling object it's the event object. See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

---

Really you should change the method to:

```
selectList.on("change", function (e) {
        var caller = $(this);
        var parent = caller.parents('.dropdown');
        var method = parent.data('method');


        if (method == 'redirect') {
            window.location = caller.val();
        }
```

Saving multiple calls to `$(this)` is more efficient.

---

also `parents()` can return multiple objects especially if your using a class selector so your code around this area isn't very robust. If you expect multiples you should deal with it (maybe use an [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)), if you don't use [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) instead